# Infinite while loop not working properly in php7 any alternative?

Tags: php-7.2

when we tried to made Infinite loop using while, but works abnormally that means after certain time it terminated unexpectedly. In Below we attached sample Code.

while(true){

//some codes are placed here for infinite Times Need to Execute
}

Comment: Could you give the exact error you are facing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.